# Install Neovim 0.6 Prerelease in Raspberry Os (Debian)

Tags: raspberry-pi, debian, neovim, github-copilot

I'm trying to test [copilot.vim](https://github.com/github/copilot.vim)  in my raspberry Pi.

I installed all but when I try to use :Copilot appear the next message:

> Copilot: Neovim 0.6 prerelease required to support ghost text

I was searching but the last beta version of Neovim released is 0.5.1

Answer (score 2):

Just install the neo-vim nightly pre-release.
Download the appimage, and move it to a directory indexed in PATH so you can invoke it by typing `nvim`

```sh
curl -LO https://github.com/neovim/neovim/releases/latest/download/nvim.appimage

chmod u+x nvim.appimage

sudo mv nvim.appimage /usr/local/bin/nvim
```

Answer (score 0):

GitHub Copilot is an AI pair programmer which suggests line completions and entire function bodies as you type. GitHub Copilot is powered by the OpenAI Codex AI system, trained on public Internet text and billions of lines of code.

Copilot.vim is a Vim plugin for GitHub Copilot. For now, it requires a Neovim 0.6 prerelease and a Node.js installation.

To learn more about GitHub Copilot, visit https://copilot.github.com.